# How to send the array to querystring

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> Friends, i need the help for sending array to the querystring . just a simple html page.

```
var obj = [];
    obj[0] = {Guest:"Ramkumar", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[1] = {Guest:"Sathish", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[2] = {Guest:"Suresh", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[3] = {Guest:"Ganesh", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };

var x = JSON.stringify(obj);


window.location = "view.html?Object=" + JSON.stingify(obj);
```

> When redirect i got the error like this.. . **Internal Server error.**

Comment: It's `stringify` not `stingify`, and the error is on the server, so it's probably not expecting whatever it is you're sending

Comment: I'll have to expand [toSting](https://github.com/atmd83/toSting) with a stingify method

Comment: adeneo is right, plus, that window.location you can add "view.html?Object="+ x; you have already stringify the object

Comment: Everytime when you get `Internal Server error` look in your server `error_log` before any other actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [];
    obj[0] = {Guest:"Ramkumar", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[1] = {Guest:"Sathish", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[2] = {Guest:"Suresh", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };
    obj[3] = {Guest:"Ganesh", City: "Madurai", Mobile: "9578606320", Email: "bsrsms@gmail.com", Address:"first street" };

var x = JSON.stringify(obj);


window.location = "view.html?Object=" + JSON.stingify(obj);
```

Contains an error.

```
window.location = "view.html?Object=" + JSON.stingify(obj);
```

should be

```
window.location = "view.html?Object=" + JSON.stringify(obj);
```

JSON.**stringify**, not JSON.**stingify**

Your server side is probably not expecting the faulty output of your code.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, you have already stringified your object into the variable x, so there's no need to stringify it again. Therefore you could also use

```
window.location = "view.html?Object=" + x;
```

Comment: ...and I suggest to escape url

Comment: Can you please let us see the server side, @Pikachu?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `encodeURIComponent` to encode the URL properly.

```
var x = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
window.location = "view.html?Object=" + x;
```

In addition to the `stingify` typo, that should be `stringify`.

Also, since the `GET` variable seems to be quite large, you may want to consider switching to `POST`. I recommend checking out [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: What `error_log` says about this? Perhaps there is error in other place.

Comment: @Pikachu: Internal server error is a server error - as the name suggests, and not related to the JS you posted.